# Python 'NoneType' TypeError when trying to access dictionary data

Tags: python, django, spotify, nonetype, spotipy

I'm using Spotify's API through Spotipy, and trying to get the name of a track. I've used the API with Javascript a fair amount, and had no issues trying to do essentially this same thing, and I've come up against a wall here.

Basically, I get the tracks of a given playlist using this endpoint: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlists-tracks/, and I am trying to extract the names of the tracks.

This will output the 'track object' of a given track:

```
playlist_items = spotify.playlist_tracks(playlist_nameid[playlist])['items']
        for item in playlist_items:
            track_object = item['track']
```

[Here's a picture of the output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVSTN.png)

I know I'm overwriting the track_object, I've just stripped it down for testing.

If I try `track_object = item['track']['name']` I get the error

```
TypeError at /radio/login
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

To make sure `item['track']` is a subscriptable object, I tried `type(item['track'])`, and the output was `{}`. I'm quite confused at this point, because the error seems to be telling me the dictionary object is of type 'none'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the items in `playlist_items` is None or `item['track']` is None. The following might work better for you:

```
item.get('track', {}).get('name')
```

You can filter out none items with:

```
for item in playlist_items:
    if item is None:
        continue
```

Or you can protect the original fetch with:

```
item and item.get('track', {}).get('name')
```

Comment: This gives me the error

`AttributeError at /radio/login
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Although if I remove `.get('name')`, it gives me the track object.

Comment: Then it's definitely that one of the instances is none.

Comment: I tried both filtering the none items and protecting the original fetch, and doing both, and it still gave the same error. This is what I have:

`playlist_items = spotify.playlist_tracks(playlist_nameid[playlist])['items']
        for item in playlist_items:
            if item is None:
                continue

            track_object = item and item.get('track', {}).get('name')`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of @schillingt - filtering the none items was the correct approach. Instead of filtering the playlist items, I had to filter the track objects.

This returns a list of the playlists' track names:

```
playlist_items = spotify.playlist_tracks(playlist_nameid[playlist])['items']
        title = []
        for item in playlist_items:
            if item['track'] is None:
                continue
            else:
                title.append(item['track']['name'])
```