# Spotipy: ‘TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable’ when trying to access playlists

Tags: python, typeerror, spotify, nonetype, spotipy

Revisiting some year-old code for getting musical features data through the Spotify API, I’m now getting this error when I try to re-run it.

This is the gist of my code:

https://github.com/rjdkirk/spotipy_study/blob/main/Spotify_playlists_v1.py

More specifically, this is the main function, after the Spotify authentication:

```
def analyze_playlist(creator, playlist_id):

    playlist_features_list = ["artist","album","track_name","track_id","acousticness","danceability","energy","key","loudness","mode","speechiness","instrumentalness","liveness","valence","tempo","duration_ms","time_signature"]

    playlist_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = playlist_features_list)

    playlist = sp.user_playlist_tracks(creator, playlist_id)["items"]
    for track in playlist:
        playlist_features = {}
        playlist_features["artist"] = track["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"]
        playlist_features["album"] = track["track"]["album"]["name"]
        playlist_features["track_name"] = track["track"]["name"]
        playlist_features["track_id"] = track["track"]["id"]

        audio_features = sp.audio_features(playlist_features["track_id"])[0]
        for feature in playlist_features_list[4:]:
            playlist_features[feature] = audio_features[feature]

        track_df = pd.DataFrame(playlist_features, index = [0])
        playlist_df = pd.concat([playlist_df, track_df], ignore_index = True)

    return playlist_df
```

And the output with error, running a test program on just one playlist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Spots_test.py", line 34, in <module>
    playlists_df = analyze_playlist('Spotify', '37i9dQZF1DWZd79rJ6a7lp')
  File "Spots_test.py", line 27, in analyze_playlist
    playlist_features[feature] = audio_features[feature]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

As far as I can work out it seems to be particular tracks within playlists that are the issue, but I can't work out how to get around it. I have found this, but I’m stuck trying to implement the fix:

[Python 'NoneType' TypeError when trying to access dictionary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495761/python-nonetype-typeerror-when-trying-to-access-dictionary-data)

Any suggestions greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your code here

Comment: I am not sure but I doubt that an empty playlist would return None and you are trying to perform actions on it with the expected return type in mind. If you could show the error traceback, that would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

The release radar this week only had 29 tracks, so I wonder if track 0 was borked, and returned the None type.

Thanks!!! I've had a script running to back up my Discover Weekly and Recent Releases running fine for years but for some reason it broke on this weeks RR.

For some reason this was grabbing a None "track" at the start of the RR playlist, DW was working fine, so prob a error on the Spotify end.

```python
def get_track_ids(tracks):
    global logtext
    track_ids=[]
    for i, item in enumerate(tracks['items']):
        track = item['track']
        track_ids.append(track['id'])
        logtext = logtext+("%d - %s - <i>%s</i><br>" % (i, track['artists'][0]['name'], track['name']))
    return track_ids
```

I put in the try/except and worked a treat.

```python
def get_track_ids(tracks):
    global logtext
    track_ids=[]
    for i, item in enumerate(tracks['items']):
        track = item['track']
        try:
            track_ids.append(track['id'])
            logtext = logtext+("%d - %s - <i>%s</i><br>" % (i, track['artists'][0]['name'], track['name']))
        except:
            pass    
    return track_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using try: except:

```
try:
    for feature in playlist_features_list[4:]:
        playlist_features[feature] = audio_features[feature]
except:
    pass
```

I've seen a lot of discussion about whether or not this as good or bad practice for ignoring NoneTypes so I may come back to it, but for now it works.